# Understanding the linux audio subsystem (alsa). any recommended book?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox, subsystem

I am trying to fiddle with linux audio sub-system. Basically, I am trying to understand how audio input/ouput flows (use of audio encoders etc) when running a linux image on Vbox. Anyone know a good place to start or a good book to refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to follow the [Linux Audio User Group](http://linuxaudio.org/). They have a number of resources on their website and their [mailing list](http://linuxaudio.org/mailarchive/) is also quite active.

This should act as a good starter guide: http://lau.linuxaudio.org/Sound-HOWTO.html